# Serialize an XML object to string

Tags: xml, serialization, dart

Why is XmlSerializer deprecated? How can I print a string representation of an XML node?

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with 
[Intent to Deprecate and Remove: XSLT](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/zIg2KC7PyH0%5B1-25-false%5D) The discussions mentions to remove the dependency on `libxml` therefore I assume the entire client side XML support should be removed.